# How to pull duplicates in transactional data based on date and other fields

Tags: sql, sas

I am looking at transactional data such as my credit card statement. I want to ensure that I am not getting my card swiped twice. The fields that I have are card number (I have multiple), amount of transaction, transaction date, merchant code, merchant name, and transaction code. 
To know if it is a true duplicate transaction, I want to know if the merchant code, merchant name, and transaction amount appear more the once. I also want to make sure that the transaction was within 5 days of each other if all else matches. 
I am doing the work in SAS code, but I can also do in PROC SQL. So far in SAS I’ve sorted the data and then pulled a table that only holds duplicates, but since I’ve sorted the data, It will only call it a duplicate if the dates are the exact same date instead of the 5 days rule mentioned.

I did a simple PROC SORT.

```
PROC SORT DATA=WORK.TRANSACTIONS
OUT=WORK.TRANSACTIONS1
DUPOUT=WORK.SORTSORTEDDUPS
NODUPKEY;
BY CARD NUMBER TRANSACTION_AMOUNT TRANSACTION_DATE MERCHANT_CODE MERCHANT_NAME TRANSACTION_CODE
```

What do I need to incorporate to add my rule of transaction within 5 days?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an additional pass, retaining (and comparing to) the last transaction date as per the below.  Note the change in the sort BY statement (you'll need to update the `proc sort` also).

```
data duplicates;
  set work.transactions1;
  by BY CARD NUMBER TRANSACTION_AMOUNT MERCHANT_CODE MERCHANT_NAME TRANSACTION_CODE TRANSACTION_DATE; 
  retain datecheck 0; 
  if first.TRANSACTION_CODE then datecheck=0;
  else if TRANSACTION_DATE-datecheck le 5 then output;
  datecheck=TRANSACTION_DATE;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's create our practice data source:

```
DATA MY_CREDIT_CARDS;
    INPUT
        C_NUMBER
        TRANC_AMOUNT
        TRANSC_DATE :DATE10.
        TRANSC_CODE
        MERCH_CODE
        MERCH_NAME $10.;
    FORMAT TRANSC_DATE DDMMYY10.;
    CARDS;
1 100 17JAN1990 1 1 AMAZON
2 200 01JAN1990 2 8 WALLMART
4 100 04JAN1990 3 5 CRUSTYKRAB
2 200 07JAN1990 4 7 NETFLIX
1 300 01JAN1990 5 2 GOOGLEPLAY
3 200 17JAN1990 6 8 WALLMART
5 100 18JAN1990 7 2 GOOG.PLAY
5 300 19JAN1990 8 2 GOOGLEPLAY
2 200 22JAN1990 9 8 WALLMART
4 200 20JAN1990 10 2 GOOGLEPLAY
1 100 03JAN1990 11 2 GOOG.PLAY
1 100 17JAN1990 12 1 AMZN
;
RUN;
```

Result:

[image]

Now, first of all, I recommend not to use descriptive fields such as a names (merchant name in this case) as keys, because descriptive fields can be very variable, i.e. someone can register AMAZON as AMZN or AMAZN, or any combination you could imagine as the merchant name. Use ID fields instead. So, assuming merchant code is an unique ID, I think that is enough to identify the merchant.

Considering the above, using **PROC SQL** you could do something like this to find duplicates based on the rule you provide (and without the need of using any other extra-step):

```
PROC SQL;

/*The following assuming each record are unique
  (identified by 'transaction code' in this case),
  otherwise you must handle duplicate records properly.*/

    SELECT
        DISTINCT A.*,
        CASE WHEN
            B.TRANSC_CODE IS NOT NULL
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DUPLICATED 
    FROM MY_CREDIT_CARDS AS A
    LEFT JOIN MY_CREDIT_CARDS AS B
    ON  
        A.MERCH_CODE = B.MERCH_CODE AND
        A.TRANC_AMOUNT = B.TRANC_AMOUNT AND
        A.TRANSC_CODE ^= B.TRANSC_CODE AND
        A.TRANSC_DATE >= INTNX('day',B.TRANSC_DATE,-5) AND
        A.TRANSC_DATE <= INTNX('day',B.TRANSC_DATE,5)
    ;

/*You could use an ORDER BY clause to sort the
  results as you want.*/

RUN;
```

The result would be:

[image]

Now you have a new column named "DUPLICATED" showing 1 if found the value as duplicated and 0 if not.

Hope it helps.